# Fix for "Insufficient text color contrast ratio" adds an incorrect attribute

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I got a "Insufficient text color contrast ratio" warning in my layout. When I used the "Fix" option in the warning screen, it added an attribute `android:hintTextColor` to my text view in the xml file.

When I built the project, I got an error saying that the above attribute was not found. When I searched through all the attributes for the `TextView`, the most similar attribute I could find is `textColorHint`.

Is this a bug in Android Studio? Or did I get something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It might be a bug and warnings can most of the times be ignored

Comment: Where should I report this bug? In the Android Studio repo?

Answer (score 4):

You just go to this type of side website for a color contrast ratio calculator. Like
[https://coolors.co/contrast-checker/ffffff-006fe6](https://www.coolors.co/contrast-checker)

[image: Stem1] Now, input your text color and background color. Then Click on to Enhance Button[image]. You can adjust the text color, background color, or both colors. Maybe it will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This warning does not require any Attribute to be added, all you need to do is to enhance the contrast between the text and the background.

e.g. Set font to white if your background is black

If there is no improvement, you can try to use less complicated patterns as background.

Comment: I use TextInputLayout without any color attributes and I think it's bad choice either way to set attributes on single ui elements. I use an app theme...

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:background="@color/white"` and `android:textColorHint="@color/white"` in TextInputEditText and the warning will be gone. see below how I used it.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/dru_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type Something"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/dru_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Edit: As the above code will hide InputLayout border to avoid that set you parent view color to white see the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/dru_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type Something"
    android:textColorHint="@color/black">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/dru_edit_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing the solution for the warning. But my question was more about why Android Studio adds an incorrect attribute when I use it's suggested fix.